# Sorting datatool alphabetic first

Tags: sorting, datatool

I'd like to sort may data first alphabetic and then by upper and lowercase. Is that possible?

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{document}

\DTLnewdb{teste}

\newcommand{\addtst}[2]{
\DTLnewrow{teste}
\DTLnewdbentry{teste}{oque}{#1}
\DTLnewdbentry{teste}{quando}{#2}
}

\addtst{alga}{julho}

\addtst{Avestruz}{dezembro}

\addtst{Buxo}{janeiro}

\DTLsort{oque}{teste}

\DTLforeach{teste}{\oque=oque,\quando=quando}{\oque: \quando

}

\end{document}
```

I'd like to have:

- Avestruz: dezembro
- alga: julho
- Buxo: janeiro

Comment: What about `\dtlsort{oque}{teste}{\dtlicompare}` which does a case `i`ncensitive `compare`?